# Jquery Confirm and CodeIgniter Delete

Tags: jquery, codeigniter, dialog, confirm

I'm working with this admin panel template confirm box.

http://themepixels.com/main/themes/demo/webpage/shamcey/elements.html

When i click confirm box's ok button ajax part wont work.

I dont understand why it isnt working?

Here my code:

//Jquery Part

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
if(jQuery('.confirmbutton').length > 0) {
    jQuery('.confirmbutton').click(function(){
        jConfirm('Can you confirm this?', 'Confirmation Dialog', function(r) {
             if(r==true){
                var article_id=$(this).attr("id");
                 $.ajax({
                    type:"POST",
                    url: "<?php echo site_url()?>admin/delete",data: "id="+article_id+"&categ=article",asynchronous: true,cashe: false,beforeSend: function(){},
                    success: function(){
                    $('#delete_link_'+article_id).hide();
                    }
                    }); 
             }
        });
    });
}
});
</script>
```

//HTML

```
<tr id="delete_link_15">
<td>15</td>
<td>1</td>
<td>asg</td>
<td>etc</td>
<td>etc</td>
<td>
<span class="btn-group">
<a class="btn btn-small confirmbutton"><i class="icon-trash"></i></a>
</span>
</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: can you place: `console.log('Before If')` just before `if(r==true)` condition, and `console.log('Inside If')` just after `if(r==true){`

Comment: var parca=jQuery(this).parent('span').parent('td').parent('tr').attr("id");
This part isnt working.

Comment: <tr id="delete_'.$satir->id.'"><td><span class="btn-group">
<a href="'.site_url().'yonetici/duzenle?id='.$satir->id.'&tur=manset" class="btn btn-small"><i class="icon-pencil"></i></a>
                                                            <a class="btn btn-small confirmbutton"><i class="icon-trash"></i></a>
                                                            </span>
                                                        </td>
                                                     </tr>

Comment: `var article_id=$(this).attr("id");` - invalid context for retrieving `id` attribute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTML Code

```
<tr id="delete_link_15">
<td>15</td>
<td>1</td>
<td>asg</td>
<td>etc</td>
<td>etc</td>
<td>
<span class="btn-group">
<a class="btn btn-small confirmbutton" onclick="deleteArticle('15')"><i class="icon-trash"></i></a>
</span>
</td>
</tr>
```

Jquery code

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
function deleteArticle(article_id)
{
             var r=confirm("Can you confirm this?")
             if(r==true){

                 $.ajax({
                    type:"POST",
                    url: "<?php echo site_url()?>admin/delete",data: "id="+article_id+"&categ=article",asynchronous: true,cashe: false,beforeSend: function(){},
                    success: function(){
                    $('#delete_link_'+article_id).hide();
                    }
                    }); 
             }

}
</script>
```